# One big .NET class library vs multiple smaller ones -- what are the tradeoffs?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, class-library

I'm working on a C# app that makes use of interop to interact with several of our DLLs that export C-linkage functions. Because our product consists of more than one executable, I moved all the interop code and many shared classes into a C# class library, and reference it in the C# executable projects.

I'm considering breaking this monolithic C# class library up into a few, more granular class libraries for a few reasons, including:

- When I initially set this up, it was less clear which executable projects would need which classes. The app has matured somewhat since then, and it's now clear that a significant percentage of the classes in the library are only used by a single executable...
- Our C-linkage DLLs have dependencies that very occasionally fail on a user machine[1]. That prevents **all** our executables from running, even the ones that don't make use of that particular DLL.
- Startup time for our primary app is high (> 2 seconds). As soon as we use *anything* in our .NET class library, (I think) it loads *everything* (DLLs included).

My question is about the factors to consider before deciding whether to stay with a single class library, or break things up into smaller, more independent libraries. For example, is the per-library overhead in (runtime) resource footprint or loading time significant enough to affect the decision?

[1]: If they have a broken driver install, for example.

Comment: Generally speaking - more projects == slower compilation. How _much_ slower? Well, that depends.

Comment: I'm less concerned with build time (up to a point) than I am with runtime performance and resource footprint. I'm expecting to split a single project up into, let's say, five libraries. Since the overall amount of code being compiled would be roughly the same, I wouldn't expect the overhead of four additional projects to add significantly to build time.

Comment: Five libraries is a tiny number. We have literally hundreds of separate assemblies in our largest application (not including NuGet packages) and that works just fine. The startup time is very fast.

Comment: i don't think that, in the order of magnitude of "five", there will be _any_ significant difference.

Comment: It seemed like a reasonable question to me...

Comment: @MatthewWatson - Cool. That's what I thought, and it's good enough for me to go forward on this. I just wanted to avoid the possibility of an expensive learning opportunity (I'm one of those 10x developers you hear about ... multiply all of my estimates by 10x)

Comment: IMHO, it's a very broad and open-ended question, more a discussion-starter about "which is better".

Comment: It is opinion based and / or there are a lot of different answers. So that is not very useful. And that happens to be a downvote reason.

Comment: Maybe you should have asked: *I have this setup with 3 projects, C and .Net. Here is the minimal code needed that demonstrates this takes 2 seconds to startup. What are my options to reduce that time by 50% so that I'm closer to or below 1 second? I tried splitting into more assemblies but that didn't improve things.* Note that if you have working code, CodeReview.se might be an option to get performance related advice. As for project structure: Software Engineering.SE has posts on that. Not sure if they would take this one. Check their help before posting there.

Comment: @rene "there are a lot of different answers. So that is not very useful."

I tried to avoid the opinion-based thing, but I'd respectfully argue that the answer can be very useful. In this case, the answer "we have literally hundreds of separate assemblies in our largest application ... startup time is very fast" gives a very high lower bound for expecting performance issues.

Comment: All answers to questions can be useful. Just not all questions will fly here.

Comment: Performance and load times also depend on hardware used, exact framework version, specific dependencies you have, etc. Start-up time is very fast doesn't tell me a thing. What is startup-time? How is that measured? What are these 100 assemblies? Are those all loaded or not? If not, why not?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question with its _["no actual problem to be solved"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_, kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and/or _review_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!